# Making knockout subscribers off for a model and turn it on back again

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm new to knockout and don't know if I'm doing this right at all or not

I have a shopping cart editor, just like knockout live examples, except the fact that I want to have a more advanced **product selector**. my products have actually **two** kind of code which user must be able to enter one of those and get product's complete details on his cart. so I would have two inputs for each kind of code and when the user enter a code in any of those, I should make an ajax call and load product info (including productId, productName, the_other_code, etc.).

I'v tried to this by subscribing to both code1 & code2 - make ajax call and set model's data after getting data from the server, but it makes a kind of recursive event(subscribe) firing and thus calling ajax methods repeatedly.thus I believe if can set knockout subscription OFF during the `SetData` method, then the recursive act would not happens.

```
function Product(data) 
{
    var self = this;

    self.ProductId = ko.observable();
    self.Code1 = ko.observable();
    self.Code2 = ko.observable();
    self.Title = ko.observable();

    self.SetData = function (itemdata) {
        self.ProductId (itemdata ? itemdata.ProductId : null);
        self.Code1(itemdata ? itemdata.Code1 : null);
        self.Code2(itemdata ? itemdata.Code2 : null);
        self.Title(itemdata ? itemdata.Title : null);
    };

    self.SetData(data);

    self.Code1.subscribe(function (value) 
    {
        var productInfo = Ajax_GetPartDataWithCode1(value);
        self.SetData(productInfo );
    });

    self.Code2.subscribe(function (value) {
        var productInfo = Ajax_GetPartDataWithCode2(value);
        self.SetData(productInfo );
    });
}
```

any help would be greatly appricated!

Comment: Have you tried using a simple boolean flag? set it to true upon entering `SetData` and to false when exiting, then in the subscribe callbacks return right away if the flag is set

Comment: I think that should be an answer. That's how I do this, although you can also remove a subscription handler if you stored a reference to it when adding it, as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10653030/how-to-unsubscribe-the-subscribed-function-in-knockout

Comment: @antishok thank you very much. I was so into finding the solution for `ko` that i totally forget about simpler solutions :) please change your comment into an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple boolean flag should be enough. Set it to true upon entering `SetData` and to false when exiting, then in the subscribe callbacks return right away if the flag is set:

```
    var updatingData = false;

    self.SetData = function (itemdata) {
        updatingData = true;
        self.ProductId (itemdata ? itemdata.ProductId : null);
        self.Code1(itemdata ? itemdata.Code1 : null);
        self.Code2(itemdata ? itemdata.Code2 : null);
        self.Title(itemdata ? itemdata.Title : null);
        updatingData = false;
    };

    self.SetData(data);

    self.Code1.subscribe(function (value) 
    {
        if (updatingData) return;
        var productInfo = Ajax_GetPartDataWithCode1(value);
        self.SetData(productInfo);
    });

    self.Code2.subscribe(function (value) {
        if (updatingData) return;
        var productInfo = Ajax_GetPartDataWithCode2(value);
        self.SetData(productInfo);
    });
```